# Cpp overwrite mixture overcomlicated

Tags: c++, c++11

I practicing my cpp knowledge and stuck with this code. The Output of this code would be:

```
1.Executing: CMessage motto3{motto1+motto2};
2.CMessage add operator function called.
3.CText constructor called.
4.CMessage constructor called.
5.CText constructor called.
6.CText move assignment operator function called.
7.CText destructor called.
8.CText add operator function called.
9.CText constructor called.
10.CText move constructor called.
11.CText destructor called.
12.CText move assignment operator function called.
13.CText destructor called.
14.CText constructor called.
15.CMessage move constructor called.
16.CText assignment operator function called.
17.CText destructor called.
 Done!!
```

As far as I understand, the "+" of CMessage evaluated, so the 2. printed
Then, in this overriding operator, the "CMessage message" will be constructed. Before the constructor of the "message" being called, the constructor of CText would be called with empty parameter first (3.), then come constructor of CMessage (4.). After that the constructor of the CText with "str" would be called again to initialize "m_Text" (5.).
But how come the 6. line??? Im getting lost from this point, could anyone please explain why?

```
// Ex8_09.cpp Creeping inefficiencies
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class CText
{
private:
  char* pText;

public:
  // Function to display text
  void showIt() const
  {
    cout << pText << endl;
  }

  // Constructor
  CText(const char* pStr = "No text")
  {
    cout << "CText constructor called." << endl;
    size_t len{ strlen(pStr) + 1 };
    pText = new char[len];                                 // Allocate space for text
    strcpy_s(pText, len, pStr);                            // Copy text to new memory
  }

  // Copy constructor definition
  CText(const CText& txt)
  {
    cout << "CText copy constructor called." << endl;
    size_t len{ strlen(txt.pText) + 1 };
    pText = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(pText, len, txt.pText);
  }

  // Move constructor definition
  CText(CText&& txt)
  {
    cout << "CText move constructor called." << endl;
    pText = txt.pText;
    txt.pText = nullptr;
  }

  // Destructor to free memory allocated by new
  ~CText()
  {
    cout << "CText destructor called." << endl;            // Just to track what happens
    delete[] pText;                                        // Free memory
  }

  // Assignment operator for CText objects
  CText& operator=(const CText& txt)
  {
    cout << "CText assignment operator function called." << endl;
    if (this != &txt)                                      // Check addresses not equal
    {
      delete[] pText;                                      // Release memory for 1st operand
      size_t length{ strlen(txt.pText) + 1 };
      pText = new char[length];

      // Copy 2nd operand string to 1st
      strcpy_s(this->pText, length, txt.pText);
    }
    return *this;                                          // Return a reference to 1st operand
  }

  // Move assignment operator for CText objects
  CText& operator=(CText&& txt)
  {
    cout << "CText move assignment operator function called." << endl;
    delete[] pText;                                        // Release memory for 1st operand
    pText = txt.pText;
    txt.pText = nullptr;
    return *this;                                          // Return a reference to 1st operand
  }

  // Overloaded addition operator
  CText operator+(const CText& txt) const
  {
    cout << "CText add operator function called." << endl;
    size_t length{ strlen(pText) + strlen(txt.pText) + 1 };
    CText aText;
    aText.pText = new char[length];
    strcpy_s(aText.pText, length, pText);
    strcat_s(aText.pText, length, txt.pText);
    return aText;
  }
};

class CMessage
{
private:
  CText m_Text;                    // Object text string

public:
  // Function to display a message
  void showIt() const
  {
    m_Text.showIt();
  }

  // Overloaded addition operator
  CMessage operator+(const CMessage& aMess) const
  {
    cout << "CMessage add operator function called." << endl;
    CMessage message;
    message.m_Text = m_Text + aMess.m_Text;
    return message;
  }

  // Copy assignment operator for CMessage objects
  CMessage& operator=(const CMessage& aMess)
  {
    cout << "CMessage copy assignment operator function called." << endl;
    if (this != &aMess)               // Check addresses not equal
    {
      m_Text = aMess.m_Text;
    }
    return *this;                    // Return a reference to 1st operand
  }

  // Move assignment operator for CMessage objects
  CMessage& operator=(CMessage&& aMess)
  {
    cout << "CMessage move assignment operator function called." << endl;
    m_Text = aMess.m_Text;
    return *this;                    // Return a reference to 1st operand
  }

  // Constructor definition
  CMessage(const char* str = "Default message")
  {
    cout << "CMessage constructor called." << endl;
    m_Text = CText(str);
  }

  // Copy constructor definition
  CMessage(const CMessage& aMess)
  {
    cout << "CMessage copy constructor called." << endl;
    m_Text = aMess.m_Text;
  }

  // Move constructor definition
  CMessage(CMessage&& aMess)
  {
    cout << "CMessage move constructor called." << endl;
    m_Text = aMess.m_Text;
  }
};

int main()
{
  CMessage motto1{ "The devil takes care of his own. " };
  CMessage motto2{ "If you sup with the devil use a long spoon.\n" };

  cout << endl << " Executing: CMessage motto3{motto1+motto2}; " << endl;
  CMessage motto3{ motto1 + motto2 };
  cout << " Done!! " << endl << endl << "motto3 contains:" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `message.m_Text = a_temporary_of_type_CText` is where the move assignment operator is called. (The temporary is produced by `m_Text + aMess.m_Text` expression).

Comment: in the "message.m_Text = m_Text + aMess.m_Text;"i t must call the copy constructor for the right first, then the "+" and at last the "=" right? Why the "=" come first???

Comment: I take it back. Line 6 is printed by `m_Text = CText(str);` inside `CMessage` constructor. Which in turn is called by `CMessage message;` inside `CMessage::operator+`. The `CMessage` constructor first constructs its `m_Text` member, and then assigns to it. It also constructs and destroys a temporary CText. All in all, it's responsible for lines 3 through 7